# jQuery slide out or off canvass navigation

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a toggle when the user clicks/taps an icon to slide the #wrapper left 200px and then and then back once its clicked/tapped again. This is the code I am trying to work with:

```
$('a.navToggle').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').toggle(function () {
        $('this').animate({
            right: '200px'
        }, 900);
    },
    function () {
        $('this').animate({
            left: '200px'
        }, 900);
    });
});
```

The problem I'm getting is the #wrapper slides of screen completely and not just 200px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
$('a.navToggle').click(function () {
    if($("#wrapper").css("left") == "-200px")
    {  
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            left: '0'
        }, 900);
    }
    else{
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            left: '-200px'
        }, 900);
    }
});
```

Comment: I kind of works - Its slides he wrong way, but I need it to toggle each time its clicked and can only get this to work once then I have to reload the page.

Comment: Yes, that almost perfect - It does the toggle exactly how I need it - However, it slides off to the right and I need to slide the opposite way (to the left). I've tried changing the left and right but can't get it to work

Comment: Its still moving the wrapper to the right - This was the problem I've been having. If swap the number around (which should work) it doesn't do anything

Comment: if it's not what you want I really don't know what you want! **[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/L3QPp/4/)**

Comment: Thanks so much for you help, I really appreciate it - I have done a fiddle here, as you can see when you click it moves off to the right of the screen. I need it to move to left? http://jsfiddle.net/jackbarham/9m6Mq/2/

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle(function(){},function(){}`) is [Deprecated and Removed](http://api.jquery.com/category/removed/) in version 1.9

You must using greater version than that.

and using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) means to hide and show alternatively.

> Display or hide the matched elements.

That's why your code is hiding element with id `wrapper` and one click again showing it.

---

It is [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) not `'this'` without quotes.

---

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7A2g4/)

```
var i = 0,
    wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$('a.navToggle').click(function () {
    if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
        wrapper.removeAttr('style').animate({
            right: '200px'
        }, 900);
    } else {
        wrapper.removeAttr('style').animate({
            left: '200px'
        }, 900);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any idea what i can use instead?

Comment: Here is simple fiddle I have done http://jsfiddle.net/jackbarham/L3QPp/ I'm trying to get the Facebook app style navigation where the #wrapper will slide out to the left and then back again when the .navToggle is clicked